# Bootstrap - How to centre a glyphicon inside a panel?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, glyphicons

I am trying to center a glyphicon inside of a panel using Bootstrap 3. As it currently stands, the icon is positioned on the left of the panel.

Any advice is greatly appreciated.

My code:

```
<div class="panel-body">

      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-asterisk" aria-hidden="true"></span>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add Bootstrap's [`text-center`](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#type-alignment) class to your div:

```
<div class="panel-body text-center">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-asterisk" aria-hidden="true"></span>
</div>
```

**[bootply example](http://www.bootply.com/aTmh0VWAji)**

Comment: Thanks muchly, that does indeed center the icon, but strangely it also removes the styling of the panel..